# Export data like checkbox value in PDF with PHP

Tags: php, database, pdf, checkbox, extract

I have a question about exporting data from PDF files. More accurate: I am currently trying to export checkbox values from a PDF file using PHP. I need to get this data to import it into a database.

Is it possible to export data values like checkbox values out of PDF's with PHP? Is there maybe a way to use the names of the elements in the PDF as keys in PHP?

Greetings AJ

Comment: What have you tried yourself already?

Comment: I tried to open the PDF-file with "file_get_contents()", parse it to a string with "parse_str" and then getting the keys with "array_keys". 

Also I tried to add a submit-button to my PDF-document that opens the php-file. But my $_GET and my $_POST arrays are still empty.